# How to store email in variables and send it with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var transporter=nodemailer.createTransport('smtps://username@gmail.com:password@smtp.gmail.com');
exports.sendMail=functions.https.onRequest((req,res)=>{
 var mailOptions={
  to: 'sender@gmail.com',
  subject: 'Test Mail',
  html: 'Testing with Node.js'
 }
 transporter.sendMail(mailOptions,function(err,response){
  if(err)
  {
   res.send('Mail not sent');
   console.log(err);
  }
  else{
   res.send('Mail sent');
  }
 });
});
```

I want to send email to various persons over time. I want to change the **to:** address in this code dynamically. So how to get a particular(sendermailid) variable from another javascript file and send to that person. My folders are located as below the picture.
[image: Folder Locations]
How to get the variable from **assmt.js** to **index.js(cloud function js).**

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up an express server who is listening our other JS aplication like this :

```
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();
```

Now you can listen from another app on specified port :

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port);
console.log("App listening on port " + port);
```

Finally you have to intercept http post request to send your mail and get user info from the request :

```
app.post('/api/sendmail', function(req, res) {
    var mail = {
                from: req.body.user.emailFrom,
                to: req.body.user.emailTo,
                subject: "your subject",
                html: "<p>email body</p>"
                }



    transporter.sendMail(mail, function(error, response){
                    if(error){
                        console.log("Error!");
                        console.log(error);
                        res.send(JSON.stringify(error));
                    }else{
                        res.send(JSON.stringify(response));
                        console.log("Success!")
                        transporter.close();
                    }

    }
```

Your server is now ready you can start it with :

> node serverName.js

And in your other js file ( assmt.js ) you send the http request with parameter :

```
send(user : User) {
    let body = {user};
     this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:8080/api/sendconge', body)
    .subscribe(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: I am not clear about your answer. Can you please explain me briefly.